# How to obtain a value based on a certain probability

Tags: c++, probability, probability-theory

I have some functions which generate double, float, short, long random values. I have another function to which I pass the datatype and which should return a random value. Now I need to choose in that function the return value based on the passed datatype. For example, if I pass float, I need:

the probability that the return is a float is 70%, the probability that the return is a double, short or long is 10% each. I can make calls to the other function for generating the corresponding random values, but how do I fit in the probabilistic weights for the final return? My code is in C++.

Some pointers are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ random numbers have [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution). If you need [random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) of another [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) you need to base its mathematical formula on uniform distribution.

If you don't have a mathematical formula for your random variable you can do something like this:

```
int x = rand() % 10;
if (x < 7)
{
 // return float
}
else (if x == 7)
{
 // return double
}
else (if x == 8)
{
 // return short
}
else (if x == 9)
{
 // return long
}
```

Comment: You make an interesting point. I think a mathematical formula based on some probability distribution is what I would eventually like to do. There are some other variables involved, which I didn't mention in my question for reasons of simplicity. But for the time being, your solution is just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This can serve as an alternative for future references which can
get the probability of precise values such as 99.999% or 0.0001%
To get probability(real percentage) do as such:

```
//70%
double probability = 0.7;
double result = rand() / RAND_MAX;
if(result < probability)
   //do something
```

I have used this method to create very large percolated grids and it works like a charm for precision values.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if I understand correctly what you want to do, but if you just want to assure that the probabilities are 70-10-10-10, do the following:

- generate a random number `r` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
- if `r <= 7`: float
- if `r == 8`: short
- if `r == 9`: double
- if `r == 10`: long

I think you recognize and can adapt the pattern to arbitrary probability values.

Comment: I adapted your and @mmomen's solution to fit my requirements. Unfortunately I can only mark one reply as the accepted answer. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

mmonem has a nice probabilistic switch, but returning different types isn't trivial either.  You need a single type that may adequately (for your purposes) encode any of the values - check out boost::any, boost::variant, union, or convert to the most capable type (probably double), or a string representation.

Comment: I presume @Manas is focusing on the the probabilistic issue as the title of the question suggests and what the question ends with; *'how do I fit in the probabilistic weights for the final return?'*

Comment: But @Manas also doesn't seem to get the difficulties with the return value.

Comment: The global random generator function returns a _variant_t. That takes care of the return value being of different datatypes (double, float, short, long). Nonetheless, "boost::any" does sound interesting. I think I'll take a look at that just out of curiosity. Thanks for the pointer.