# In C++, How Can I Generate A Random Number Based Off Of A Double Value Probability?

Tags: c++, probability

I have an event that should have a 0.5% probability of occurring (not very often).

How can I generate a random number based on this probability?

Would something like this be sufficient, I don't believe so as srand returns an integer...

```
double rate = 0.05;
if((srand() % 100) < rate)
{
    std::cout << "Event Occurred" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `srand` doesn't generate random numbers; `rand` does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain a value based on a certain probability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572343/how-to-obtain-a-value-based-on-a-certain-probability)

Comment: @MatthewMoss's dup is correct, but wanted to add that the trick is remembering that a 0.05% probability is equivalent to saying a 5/10000 probability. In other words, you just have to scale your values appropriately so that everything is an integer.

Comment: The answers in that dup are terrible.

Comment: As of C++11, you normally want to use something like `uniform_int_distribution` to get the numbers into a range. If your compiler is old enough it doesn't include that, there are [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10219422/179910) that at least tell how to do that part correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());
std::bernoulli_distribution d(0.005);
bool b = d(rng); // true 0.5% of the time; otherwise false
```